# Dynamic IOC mapping with UnityContainer - How can I achieve?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I'm trying to create a smart IOC resolver using my `UnityContainer` that will receive information from a third party service as part of the resolving process.

If a config entry would typically look like this (I've create alias's for all types):

```
<type type="IMyInterface" mapTo="MyInstance">
    <lifetime type="Hierarchical" />
</type>
```

I would like to remove the mapTo, and provide it in runtime (per each relevant resolve request).

Now, I've tried doing this by creating a `UnityContainerExtension` and a `BuilderStrategy` and things got messy and work partially.

Since I only want to override the mapTo part, I guess that maybe I've gone to far.

So, how can I achieve that kind of functionality? 
Is there anyway I can override the mapTo's getter\strategy?

Comment: Are you going to resolve `IMyInterface` directly? or another type that eventually depends on `IMyInterface`? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I'm going to perform an api call, get back a hint that will help me choose the "mapTo" type (which implements IMyInterface) and I want the UnityContainer to new mapTo type. Kind of a mapTo runtime Factory.

Example: The interface is IVehicle. When I need to resolve the IVehicle I need to compute the mapped type. I want to perform an api call and return the correct type (could be Truck or SportsCar in this example).

Comment: Why don't you resolve the concrete type directly? e.g. Truck or SportsCar

Comment: Since I have a central api that decides about the mapping dynamically. Think of it like a feature based behavior. I don't want to change my configs, but rather get the information from a third party, in runtime. At any point of time, the type can change and I want my application to adapt on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I found the hook.

First you need to create a `BuilderStrategy` that will lookup for the new mapping:

```
public class DynamicMappingBuildStrategy: BuilderStrategy
{
    public override void PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context)
    {
        var policy = context.Policies.Get<IBuildKeyMappingPolicy>(context.BuildKey);

        if (policy != null)
        {
            context.BuildKey = policy.Map(context.BuildKey, context);
        }
        else
        {
            var oldMapping = context.BuildKey;
            var mappedType = DynamicMapper.GetMapping(oldMapping.Type);
            context.BuildKey = new NamedTypeBuildKey(mappedType, null);
            var lifetime = context.PersistentPolicies.Get<ILifetimePolicy>(oldMapping, true);

            if (lifetime != null)
            {
                context.PersistentPolicies.Set(lifetime, context.BuildKey);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to create a `UnityContainerExtension` that will add the `BuilderStrategy` in the correct `UnityBuildStage`:

```
public class DynamicMappingBehaviorExtension : UnityContainerExtension
{
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        this.Context.Strategies.AddNew<DynamicMappingBuildStrategy>(UnityBuildStage.TypeMapping);
    }
}
```

Then you need to configure your container to use the new extension:

```
<containers>
            <container>
                <extensions>
                    <add type="MyNamespace.DynamicMappingBehaviorExtension, MyDll" />
                </extensions>
....More configuration.....
```

And then you need to add your type mapping without a mapTo:

```
<type type="IVehicle">
    <lifetime type="Hierarchical" />
</type>
```